# Accessing a CDI SessionScoped bean from an EJB @Asynchronous invocation

Tags: asynchronous, dependency-injection, ejb, cdi, session-scope

I have a process which takes a long time to compute so it's marked as `@Asynchronous` in a Stateless EJB. When the process finishes, I'd like it to access a `SessionScoped` bean from the session which started the process to store the results.

Is that possible? How?

Answer (score 1):

You could `@Inject` the needed EJB, but that probably won't work because you have no guarantee that session will still be available when your asynchronous method invocation finishes. You're probably going to have to find another solution if you want to use asynchronous methods.